# Flutter - CupertinoPageTransition second route transition opacity

Tags: ios, flutter

I noticed that the CupertinoRouteTransition lowers the opacity of the second route while the transition parallax effect takes place. In my opinion this looks ugly for a lot of pages and it is also not native iOS behaviour.

After some scavenging into CupertinoPageTransition and CupertinoRouteTransitionMixin I didn't find any way of changing this behaviour without a custom rewrite of the CupertinoPageTransition.

I am fairly new to Flutter and I'm not sure about this tho. Is there something I don't see or some more straight forward way to change this behaviour without a custom CupertinoTransition implementation? Thanks!

[Video with what i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s6g5.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is a (bug or feature?) in the way the Flutter engine renders material colors. When the primary color of the app was 0xF0F1FAFF, the cupertino page transition behaved like in the linked video, but when the color was 0xFFF1FAFF (variation only on the red channel) the transition behaves normally.